# How can we get users to participate more in Meta?

Tags: new-members, participation, meta-discussion

[Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) went live in mid-2020 and I'm quite happy with the participation level on the "main" site compared to other new SE sites, but I would like more people to participate in Meta discussions as well. We have a lot of questions on Meta about, for example, reasons for voting to close questions, but often get zero answers and comments.

Points (reputation) aren't counted on Meta sites the way they are on Main sites, and while there's still badges on Meta sites, I think very few of our users care about that, so what can we do to incentivize more participation on Meta?

**I seek answers apart from using the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.**

Comment: Have you tried linking meta questions in comments or on chat room?

Comment: @Pandya People don't seem to need to be shown the Meta questions: the active users are aware of the Meta site, and I can even see that many of them do go there and look at the questions, as their profiles say "active yesterday" or "active 5 hours ago" whenever I check, but there's just no discussion: no answer Meta questions, no discussion, no one asking their own questions, etc.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I know (mod at Travel Stack Exchange) is to feature a question.
A mod can add the feature tag to the question you want to be seen and it shows up in a field next to the questions or answers in 'computer' view and below the questions or answers when using a phone. (I do not remember how they show up in the app but I think they do.)
At this time on this site there is the 'featured': "Swag is coming back!" and "New Feature: Table Support". Your site featured ones would join those which are network wide.

The Feature tag does 'fall off' after about a month and can be taken off at any time and can be re-added if wanted.

You can have a few at the same time, how many depends on whether there are more questions that wants that spot. If there are more feature tagged questions than there are spaces they take turns, randomly as far as I understand.

What we do on travel is have a competition running there, which helps people there the first time, but those do not really start to use the Meta site. I think for that you better ask provocative (but not reportable) content.

Comment: Now I wish my question said "besides using the featured tag", since many of the Meta questions referred to in my question, have in fact been featured.

Comment: Write questions for Meta which you feel your community may react on. Which I would not know as I do not know your community. Whether things are on or off topic are ones that worked for us.